# Show image on windows using imagemagick

Tags: c++, windows, image-processing, visual-c++, imagemagick

I am using [ImageMagick](https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick) for a few modifications in images. My requirement is to capture desktop, update the captured image and show in the window (Canvas, Form or simple Win32 API image).

Everything working perfectly except showing a converted image on the window.

As per [this](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=21070) discussion, display functionality of image magick is only supported by Linux and Mac (Please correct me if anything wrong).

The same forum suggested to use **im_display** to show the image on window. However, I am not able to locate any function related im_display() in the image magick library (Please correct me here if any additional include required).

When I am trying to call following code from visual studio then getting **"delegate library support not built-in '' (X11) @ error/display.c/DisplayImages/16224**" error:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    try
    {

        Magick::InitializeMagick(NULL);
        Image screen("screenshot:");
        screen.display();
    }

    catch (exception &error_)
    {
        cout << "Caught exception: " << error_.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So the following are two primary questions:

- Is it possible to show an image using image magick on windows (Form or canvas or win32)
- If it's not possible then HBITMAP will help to render an image on windows. However, I am not able to find a way to convert Image Magick data to BITMAP. Can you please provide suggestions?

Comment: Does `screen.write("win:.");` work?

Comment: @emcconville will try this once in office. One more thing is it possible to convert magic image to bitmap data.

Comment: ImageMagick can export pixel data in a bitmap stream (see last option in [Image.write](https://imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image++.html#write)), but you need to follow HBITMAP's documention for working with blob/streams.

Comment: @emcconville thanks for reply. screen.write("win:."); is working and opening imdisplay.exe in windows. However, what is want real-time rendering of live desktop in another window. For example, Some activities will goining on desktop I will capture those activities and will show on another windows like simulation.